# Continuous covariance operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a really hard time to prove that

$\int_{H} \langle h,x-m \rangle^{2}\mu(dx) $

is continuous where $\mu$ is a gaussian measure, $h$ functional on  Hilbert space.
And also why do we need the covariance operator to be trace class , the only thing that I found is in order to be the variance finite.
All helps or hints are welcome.

Comment: And what is $m$?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned it , it's the mean of the gaussian measure m

Comment: Is it continuity in $h$ that should be shown?

Comment: yes yes , that $<Qh,h>=\int_{H}<h,x-m>^{2}\mu(dx)$ is continious, in order to say that the covariance operator Q is bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we translate the integral so that the mean value is $0$:
$$q(h) := \int \langle h, x-m \rangle^2 \, \mu(dx) = \int \langle h, x \rangle^2 \, \mu_0(dx)$$

Then we take a sequence $h_k$ converging to $h$:
$$q(h_k) = \int \langle h_k, x \rangle^2 \, \mu_0(dx)$$

Now,
$$\begin{align}
|q(h_k) - q(h)| 
& = \left| \int \langle h_k, x \rangle^2 \, \mu_0(dx) - \int \langle h, x \rangle^2 \, \mu_0(dx) \right| \\
& = \left| \int \left( \langle h_k, x \rangle^2 - \langle h, x \rangle^2 \right) \, \mu_0(dx) \right| \\
& \leq \int \left| \langle h_k, x \rangle^2 - \langle h, x \rangle^2 \right| \, \mu_0(dx) \\
& = \int \left| \langle h_k, x \rangle + \langle h, x \rangle \right| \, \left| \langle h_k, x \rangle - \langle h, x \rangle \right| \, \mu_0(dx) \\
& = \int \left| \langle h_k + h, x \rangle \right| \, \left| \langle h_k - h, x \rangle \right| \, \mu_0(dx) \\
& \leq \int \|h_k + h\| \|x\| \, \|h_k - h\| \|x\| \, \mu_0(dx) \\
& = \|h_k + h\| \|h_k - h\| \int \|x\|^2 \, \mu_0(dx) \\
& < 3\|h\| \, \epsilon \int \|x\|^2 \, \mu_0(dx)  \\
\end{align}$$
which can be made as small as we want.

Sorry, I don't have time to explain more now. I will do it later, especially if you have questions.

Comment: It's really helpful, just on the last line , $\int\left \| x \right \|^{2}\mu_{0}(dx)$ is finite because Q is trace class, but $\left \| h_{k}+h \right \|\left \| h_{k}-h \right \|$ shouldn't be $\left \| h_{k}-h+h+h \right \|\left \| h_{k}-h \right \| \leq (\epsilon +2\left \| h \right \|)\epsilon$ ??

Comment: I just used that $\int e^{-x^2} \, dx$ and $\int x^2 e^{-x^2} \, dx$ are both finite, which makes $\int \|x\|^2 \, \mu_0(dx)$ finite, but I guess that this is equivalent to $Q$ being of trace class. I haven't investigated on that.

Comment: You are correct about $\left \| h_{k}-h+h+h \right < (\epsilon +2\left \| h \right \|)$, but if we take $k$ big enough we have not only $\| h_k - h \| < \epsilon$ but also $\| h_k - h \| < \| h \|$ which gives $\| h_k + h \| < 3 \|h\|$. I was actually about to write a the same inequality as you, but didn't like having $\epsilon$ in several places, so I made it this way instead.